# Return an xpath regex capturing group as a string with xpath query

Tags: php, xpath

**CONTEXT**

**Supposing the following [HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429065/compare-contrast-html-xhtml-xml-and-html5)**

```
....
<p>Whatever</p>
<div>Whatever DIV78232 Everwhat</div>
....
```

**Question:**

How could I return a plain text string containing `DIVnnnnn`, where nnnnn represents any digits.

**My investigation so far:**

The xPath replace() function will replace a pattern found inside the current DOM.

```
replace(.,'.*?(DIV\d+).*','$1') => DIV78232
```

**Why am I blocked?**

Because I want the query to return the "DIV78232" as a string, without actually replacing it in the DOM at all, just as it would return "Whatever" for the query `/p/text()` [I am trying all this on the FirePath firefox-extension]

*Note*: According to the official [DOCS](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace)

> "replace() Returns the value of the first argument with every
>   substring matched by the regular expression that is the value of the
>   second argument replaced by the replacement string that is the value
>   of the third argument."

**FINAL PURPOSE**:

My final purpose is to get the (string) IMAGE URL that matches `'.*?image:.*?"(.+?)".*'` from this (which is inside the HTML):

In this case, the query `//*[matches(.,'.*?image:.*?"(.+?)".*','i')]` returns the whole node, but I only want the first Capturing Group, which would be the IMAGE URL.

```
<script>...vp&output=xml_vast2&unviewed_position_start=1&
url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'
description_url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&
image:   "https://domain.com/xxxxxxx/public_images/2015.12/article/56797be1c46188ac438b45c3.jpg", // stretching: 'fi..</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean with plain text node? AFAICS it's an attribute value you are looking for?

Comment: @PeeHaa Thanks for your time. The question has an example that I reduced, but the final purpose is a bit more than that. I just updated the question with the specific purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a long while, but this is the result I got by combinating *replace()* and *tokenize()*

`tokenize(replace(.,'.*?image:.*?"(.+?)".*?',':@:$1:@:'),':@:')[2]`

Returns the image URL in the snippet above mentioned.

**Why/How does this work?**

- **Replace()** matches the image and wraps the capturing group with my own token separator ':@:' (Could be anything original)
- **Tokenize()** splits the replaced string in 3 parts, being the second one the capturing group I was looking for. *(It will be three parts because it is highly improbable that the document will contain ':@:' anywhere else)*

Is there any faster way to achieve this?

Thanks. All the best. Peace.