# Java Css+ html to pdf convertion exception Invalid nested tag head found, expected closing tag link

Tags: java, html, css, exception

```
    package sandbox.xmlworker;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.CssFile;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.StyleAttrCSSResolver;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.Tags;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CSSResolver;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CssResolverPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.end.PdfWriterPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipelineContext;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class D04_ParseHtmlCss {

    public static final String SRC = "/home/xxx/workspace/DemoTransformer/src/data/result.html";
    public static final String CSS = "/home/xxx/workspace/DemoTransformer/src/data/beyanname.css";
    public static final String DEST = "/home/xxx/workspace/DemoTransformer/src/data/resultpdffileson.pdf";

    public void createPdf(File file) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        // step 1
        Document document = new Document();

        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
        writer.setInitialLeading(12.5f);

        // step 3
        document.open();

        // step 4

        // CSS
        CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
        CssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(new FileInputStream(CSS));
        cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);

        // HTML
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
        htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

        // Pipelines
        PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
        HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
        CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

        // XML Worker
        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
        XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
        p.parse(new FileInputStream(SRC));

        // step 5
        document.close();
    }

    /**
     * Main method
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new D04_ParseHtmlCss().createPdf(new File(DEST));
    }
}
```

This code is from itext sandbox: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker-itext5/xml-worker-examples

Also I use itext-pdf5.4.5 and xml-worker 5.4.5

But it gives this error and I couldn't figure out how to fix this problem

```
Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.tool.xml.exceptions.RuntimeWorkerException: Invalid nested tag head found, expected closing tag link.
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker.endElement(XMLWorker.java:134)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.endElement(XMLParser.java:395)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.state.ClosingTagState.process(ClosingTagState.java:70)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parseWithReader(XMLParser.java:235)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:213)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:174)
    at sandbox.xmlworker.D04_ParseHtmlCss.createPdf(D04_ParseHtmlCss.java:59)
    at sandbox.xmlworker.D04_ParseHtmlCss.main(D04_ParseHtmlCss.java:71)
```

The head of the html file is this:

```
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>KDV1</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="beyanname.css">
</head>
```

I generated this code from xml and xslt file by using itext

Comment: The problem seems to be in the HTML, can you post it? Or at least the full `<head>`

Comment: The full head is this:

'code'<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>KDV1</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="beyanname.css">
</head>'code'

I generated this code from xml and xslt files with tanother java code

Comment: Edit your question to add the code instead of putting it in the comment. As it is, it is unreadable

Comment: The edition is done

Answer (score 0):

Your tool is using an XML parser to parse HTML. While the two looks quite alike, [they are not exactly the same](http://www.xmlobjective.com/what-is-the-difference-between-xml-and-html/). Your error is caused by a non claused `<link>` tag, which is [valid in HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) but not in XML. Which cause your parser to throw an exception. So for you the easiest solution would be to replace `XMLParser` with an HTML parser or to make sure that your HTML file is in `XHTML` which is [XML compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1429079/3072566)

Comment: Are there any easiest way to join css, xml and xslt files in a pdf file?

Comment: In your exemple you do not have any `xml` or `xslt`. But if you want to do it with pure XML, you would need to read it and the generate the PDF yourself (with the use of a PDF library of course) since XML is meant only for data. Or you could use a reporting framework that support exporting to PDF